# how to connect to a MSSQL database using Angular version 2 with Node JS

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js, angular

I am trying to connect to our companies current MSSQL database which hold our inhouse portal. I want to do this via node.js but I am currently having problems with trying to connect to the database.

Below is an example code from a app.module.ts file from an angular project. How would I implement connecting to a database from here?

```html
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ServerComponent } from './server/server.component';
import { ServersComponent } from './servers/servers.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ServerComponent,
    ServersComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { 
 
}
```

Comment: The frontend framework has nothing to do with the MSSQL connection. If you want to do it with NodeJS have a look on the existing modules for the purpose - for example [**mssql**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql)

Answer (score 2):

`Angular` (frontend) will make `HTTP` requests to your `node.js` server (backend)

Your backend server will then do whatever calls it needs to do with your `MYSQL` database.

The server will make whatever processing it needs to do on db results, then returns a JSON response for the request back to your `Angular`app.

By itself Angular is not supposed to be connected to any database, nor it should even knows about one.

[image]

As suggested in the comments, you need to focus on how to access your DB from `node.js`, for instance with [mssql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql).

Then you need need to focus on how to make HTTP requests to your server with an Angular service.

More info for example here : https://scotch.io/tutorials/creating-a-single-page-todo-app-with-node-and-angular